# How to access related data using find()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to look up information in a related document. I have this structure:

```
{
        "_id": "61e16e1edf2e211c5098852f",
        "data1": "xxx",
        "data2": "xxx",
        "data3": "xxx",
        "access": {
            "_id": "61e16e1edf2e211c5098852d",
            "data4": "xxx",
},
```

I declared the model like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Requests = mongoose.model(
  "Requests",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    data1: String,
    data2: String,
    data3: String,
    access: 
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Access"
      }
    
  })
);

module.exports = Requests;
```

I need to do two filters, the first one searches using "data1" OR the second one using "data4"

I did this method, but I have difficulties accessing the data4. How do I access the data4?

```
exports.filter = async (req, res) => {
    const query = {};
    var data = req.body;

    if (data.data1) {
        query.data1 = data.data1;
    }

    if (data.data4) {
        query.data4 = data.data4;
    }

    const sol = await Requests.find(query).populate("access");
    res.send(sol);

}
```

When I send data in "data4" I get [] even though I have results. I appreciate if anyone can help me analyze it.

UPDATE:
This is the schema where I declare data4.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var accessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  data4: String,
  data5: String,
  data6: String,
  data6: String,
});

.
.

requests: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Requests',
    required: true
  }
```

Comment: can you check data4 in the schema it is not there but in the data structure it is inside the access so I don't think it does much with any of ur documents or change the query

Comment: "data4" is contained in another schema. I already updated my code. It is declared under "Access". How can I access it?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data4')

Comment: I tried too. It gives this error:

query.access.data4= data.data4;
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'data4')

Comment: In postman I treat it like this: {"data4":"123345678"}

Answer (score 0):

```
const query = {};
const populate ={}
var data = req.body;

if (data.data1) {
      query.data1 = data.data1;
    }

if (data.data4) {
    populate.data4 = data.data4;
}


const sol = await Requests.find(query).populate({path:"access",{...populate}}).exec();
res.send(sol);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The first filter works (data1). But the second one comes with all the data, regardless of whether "data4" exists or not. I also had to remove the {} here to make it work: {...populate}. End result: const sol = await Requests.find(query).populate({path:"access",...populate}).exec();